# Why does ajax in php output to a div block with onclic just for a millisecond, refreshes and data disappears?

Tags: php, ajax

If I use this code

```
$(document).on('click', '#stavka', function(){
                            if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this data?')){
                                var action = "testvivodsucloviem";
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "action.php", 
                                type: "POST", 
                                data: {action: action}, 
                                success: function (data) {
                                    $('#testvivodsucloviem').html(data);
                                    alert(data);
                                },
                                error: function() {
                                    alert('The request failed');
                                }
                            });
} else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
```

alert works but no information is passed to the div

But if you use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

instead of

```
$(document).on('click', '#stavka', function(){
```

then the div block is filled, my question is why ? and what am i doing wrong with onclic??

file code - action.php

```
if($_POST["action"] == "testvivodsucloviem") {
    $result2 = '';
    $result2 .= 'adadww';
    echo $result2;

}
```

Comment: `$('#stavka').on('click', () => { alert(' button clicked');});` use jQuery

Comment: Alert works everywhere, div block filling doesn't work

Comment: Put code inside of `$(document).ready()` to ensure the DOM is ready, see https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/.  You may be calling `on('click'` before the DOM is ready, so put the `on('click'` inside of the `$(document).ready()`

Comment: I put $(document).ready() inside, but I didn’t see the result, when I press it, alert still fires alert(data), that is, the DOM is ready if information is passed to alert ... only it is not entered into the div

Comment: Everything works, but for some reason the page is refreshed, the data appears for a second and disappears, how can this be solved?